# Add a picture taken with camera as a background to my relative layout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have two activities; one to take a picture and another to show it and place markers in a relative layout. I'm sending the picture taken from the first activity via an Intent to the second and I decode it as a Bitmap like below but I keep receiving NullPointerException any help?:
Edit1: When I use a png ressource and add it in the XML layout everything seems to be ok.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0, getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);

Resources res = getResources();

Drawable bd =  new BitmapDrawable(res,b);

RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.touchanddrag);
rl.setBackground(bd)
setContentView(R.layout.touchanddrag);
```

Comment: can you post the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

```
setContentView(R.layout.touchanddrag); should be right after onCreate() statement.
```

You getting Null Pointer here, `rl.setBackground(bd)` as the layout is not yet initialized and you are trying access its components (your RelativeLayout).

So move this `setContentView(R.layout.touchanddrag);` after super.onCreate() statement and check how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, now i don't receive any error but The background is white! any help?

Comment: Try setBackgroudDrawable(), however there's not much difference in the two (try it once). Post the code where you passed the intent extra.

Comment: I have tested this and same thing ,,

Comment: 'Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,opts);

     ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bs);' then 'intent.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());'
     
     startActivity(intent);
}

Comment: Change, Drawable bd =  new BitmapDrawable(res,b); to Drawable bd =  new BitmapDrawable(b); and see.

Comment: :( Can you post your entire code for Activity which takes the picture.

Comment: I know that the bitmap is there since I saved it in the sdCard and seems to be ok... I have been searching a lot for a solution and didn't get it yet.

Comment: I get the picture from this </br>    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)

Comment: and sorry I add this for the options ...Options opts = new Options();

       opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Comment: Place a check to see if b or bd is null? What do you get?

Comment: Both are not null , I know that BitmapDrawable is deprecated but I think this not the problem

Comment: Turns out that there was a second setContentView below my long code and this was my problem...Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there was a second setContentView below my long code and this was my problem...Thanks for the help and hope this help someone else